# Anime about a little girl who fights a dictator after a meteor causes Mt Fuji to erupt

Tags: story-identification, anime, post-apocalyptic

I remember getting this anime recommended on a show called Imagination. This show used to air on NHK World every week. I think they talked about this anime between 2014 to 2016. I don't remember clearly when I watched it.

Genre: Post-Apocalyptic, Dystopian

At the beginning of the anime a giant skull shaped meteor or asteroid falls on Earth. It falls near Japan. Because of that Mount Fuji gets damaged and starts erupting. After few years Japan is in a very bad condition. Some people are ruling over Japan. They have their own city. The people who live inside the city live a very happy life, but the people who live outside are suffering and don't have enough.

In the first episode the girl protagonist standing in front of her mother's grave. She is crying. She looks like 7 to 8 years old. She wants to fight against this dictator. Her mom's two old sidekicks join her. One them has a mustache and is skinny, the other one is fat. All of three of them wear costumes when they fight the enemy. Does anyone know the name of the anime?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Head has the meteor, and Mt. Fuji erupting, but I don't see anything about dictators, more about survival, and it has a male protagonist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be [Yoru no Yatterman](https://myanimelist.net/anime/28155/Yoru_no_Yatterman).

Epsiode 1 begins with the meteor hiting and the main cast of a young girl and her mothers sidekicks checks out as well.

> ### Synopsis
>
> Several generations after the original Yatterman series, Leopard lives with her mother and guardians, Dorothy, Voltkatze, and Elephantus, just outside the prosperous Yatter Kingdom. She lives a happy if impoverished life, unaware of her ancestral ties to the infamous Doronbow Gang, until she discovers a mural of Doronjo, Boyacky, and Tonzura in a sealed off area of her home. It turns out that Dorothy, Voltkatze, and Elephantus are descendants of the villainous gangsters, which is why they have been forbidden from entering the hero Yatterman's Kingdom!
>
> At first, Leopard vows to never engage in villainous actions like her ancestors, but new circumstances may mean that she must go back on her word, donning the identity of villain in search of true justice.

Comment: Thanks that was the anime I was looking going to finish watching this anime after so many years

Comment: @Ragna No problem, feel free to accept the answer as correct.